# Getting unknown type name on using NSPopUpButton

Tags: ios, nspopupbutton

When I try to use NSPopUpButton, I get a "Unknown type name" while building the application. I imported the Foundation.h and even after that am getting the same error. 
Can anyone let me know what might be the issue ?

Comment: [NSPopUpButton](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSPopUpButton_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is an OS X class. You can't use it in an iOS application.

Comment: Is there any other control similar to NSPopUpButton in iOS ?

Comment: Kind of. UIPickerView is probably the closest.